# Access 2007 - Splash Screen Error

Tags: ms-access, screen, splash-screen

I had a splash screen created for my Access 2007 database, but the decision was made not to have a splash screen. I deleted it, but now every time I start the database up I get an error that says the splash screen is still being referred to.

I think I've searched everywhere in my database forms and macros, but I can't find any reference to the splash screen. Would very much appreciate some assistance.

Thanks,

Derek

Answer (score 1):

- Open the db
- Cick the OFFICE BUTTON (top left)
- Select the ACCESS OPTIONS button on bottom of window
- In the left Panel - CURRENT DATABASE should be selected/highlighted
- In the right panel, the 4th item listed is **DISPLAY FORM**: Change that pull-down menu to be NONE.
- Click OK